# printf doubles without trailing zeroes

Tags: c, printf

I declare a variable `double MyDouble;`.

If I then set `MyDouble = 1000.0 / 3.0;` and then 
`printf("%g", MyDouble);` gives 333.333 so it's lost some precision.

If I use `printf("%lf", MyDouble);` I get the precision.

The down side is if I now set `MyDouble = 5.0 / 2.0;` and use `printf("%lf", MyDouble);` I get 2.500000, so trailing zeroes.

As a general case, how can I have the precision without the trailing zeroes. I could write the double to a string using `snprintf` and the `%lf` format and then write a subroutine to strip trailing zeroes, but there must be an easier way.

Comment: Link to std::printf documentation including format specifiers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: You either want that much precision or you don't.

Comment: `l` length modifier has no effect on `f` specifier.

Comment: The documentation says the l length modifier has no effect but if I leave it off I get 333.333 so it is having an effect on my compiler.

Comment: This is not even a programming problem. When doing any form of scientific work, it is custom to specify the number of decimals used by all your calculations and then stick to that consistently. For example if you are writing a scientific report about two values, 123.45 and 123, you would write `123.45` and `123.00` respectively. They teach this in any beginner-level science class.

Comment: This is not related to C++, but the C standard library `printf` family.

Answer (score 1):

The precision of the `g` conversion specifier controls the maximum number of significant digits (see C.2011§7.21.6.1¶4). Precision is specified by a number following a decimal point. It seems you want 9 significant digits. So, try:

```
printf("%.9g", MyDouble);
```

Comment: [Demo on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/X09o3i)

Comment: Thank you jxh. That would give precison to the %f specifier but not remove trailing zeroes. "%.17g" does what I need as it formats the number to up to the full 17 characters (inc the decimal point and then strips unnecessary zeroes.

Comment: The answer was meant to have `g`, as stated in my first sentence. The code with `f` was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to avoid trailing `zero`.

```
double a= 5.0;
double b = 2.0;
printf("%.2lf\n", a/b);
```